# Output created by pagedown::html_paged not displaying properly

Tags: r, bookdown, pagedown

I am working on a project in RStudio that takes in multiple rmd files and a yml file and uses the bookdown render_book() function to produce paginated output that can be converted to pdf.

The bookdown code is as follows:

```
bookdown::render_book("prog1.Rmd", "bookdown::gitbook",    config_file = config_yml)

bookdown::render_book("prog1.Rmd", "pagedown::html_paged", config_file = config_yml)
```

The config_yml file:

```
book_filename: "Report Output"
delete_merged_file: true
new_session: yes
rmd_files: ["Start.Rmd", "prog1.rmd", "appendix.rmd"]
output_dir: ./fakedir/
language:
  label:
    fig: "FIGURE "
    tab: "TABLE "
before_chapter_script: "./fakename.R"
```

The specifications from the Start.rmd:

```
---
title: "Report"
subtitle: "`r text`"
date: "`r datetext`"
site: bookdown::bookdown_site
classoption: oneside
documentclass: book
link-citations: yes
description: "My Report"
---
```

Historically this has caused no issues, with the first bookdown call creating an html doc and the second creating a paginated version. Recently, with no code changes, the paginated version will not open properly once created. It only shows the title page followed by two blank pages. I have thus far been unable to find a reason for this. I am hoping for either a solution to this issue or an alternative method to producing a paginated document. Let me know if more info/code is needed.

Comment: I think it's something with `pagedown`. Their example isn't working right. [Check it out.](https://pagedown.rbind.io/) I get three pages of a hot mess in Chrome. I get the book rendered perfectly in Safari. When I use Atom and preview the HTML, it renders correctly there, too. What browser are you using? Have you tried alternates?

Comment: The whole report appears in firefox, but the chunks of the report are lost when attempting to print to pdf from there. Unfortunately, telling people to just open the html in firefox isn't an option.